# what is the exact meaning of the word "pleasures" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> There are many incidental **pleasures** in David Seidler's screenplay. On being thanked for some small service, Logue asks: "What are friends for?" "I wouldn't know," snaps the duke. After watching the newsreel of the coronation, the new royal family finds itself mesmerised by the sight of Hitler at Nuremberg. "What's he saying?" asks one of his daughters. "I don't know, but he seems to be saying it rather well," says the new king thoughtfully.

I understand the whole idea of this part of the review, but i'm not sure about the meaning of the word "pleasures".

Answer (score 1):

> [**pleasure**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pleasure) (n): *a cause or source of enjoyment or delight*

The reviewer says that there are many things about the screenplay of the movie -- that is, the dialogue -- which he found *pleasing*.  His two examples are of typical [understated British wit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_understatement), although neither is really very funny.